# Get an entire row based on value of cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get an entire row of data with a specific range from E to BH based on the value of whatever cell.
If for example I have value "Red" on cell P,3, I would want to selected the entire range from E3 to BH,3.

Also if I have value "Yellow" on a cell in F9, I would want to select the entire row from E9 to BH9

What I have tried so far
This is my attempt at getting the row from string "My text" however it's not working. I planned on getting the row and column in a similar fashion to so that I could get the rows from e(row) to bh(row) depending on the text

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("Table").UsedRange.Find("my text", xlValues, xlWhole)
Debug.Print "row is: " & rng1
```

Comment: Not clear if you just want to identify the `Row` that contains the required `value` _( i.e.: row number 3)_ or to extract the row (post row 3 somewhere). Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my lack of clarity. I wanted to identify the row that contains the data and extract the row. It's sorta like using the text as a primary key for a horizontal database to get other data(text) in the ranges E to BH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps using [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) and [`EntireRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow). Note that you should also test if the `Find` succeeded using `If Not rng1 Is Nothing`.

```
Set rng1 = Sheets("Table").UsedRange.Find(What:="my text", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Dim theNewRange As Range
    Set theNewRange = Intersect(rng1.EntireRow, Range("E:BH"))
End If
```

A shorter alternative using `rng1.Row`:

```
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    Dim theNewRange As Range
    Set theNewRange = Range("E:BH").Rows(rng1.Row)
End If
```

Comment: The Range.Find method is missing the 2nd parameter `After`. It should be something like: `Set rng1 = Sheets("Table").UsedRange.Find("my text", , xlValues, xlWhole)`

Comment: @EEM - good point, changed to named arguments.

Comment: Also using rng1: `Set theNewRange = Range("E:BH").Rows(rng1.Row)`

Comment: Thanks, definitely in the right direction. You helped me set the range

Comment: Nice +:) fyi maybe interested in my  approach profiting from dynamic evaluation plus using a tricky `Union()` setting. @BigBen

Answer (score 2):

### Select Row Ranges

[image]

- Note the critical parts:

  ```
  Const CopyColsAddress As String = "E:BH"
  Set ccrg = ws.Columns(CopyColsAddress)
  ccrg.Rows(i)
  ```

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub selectRowRanges()
    
    ' Constants
    Const wsName As String = "Table"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const CopyColsAddress As String = "E:BH"
    Const CritColsList As String = "F,P"
    Const CriteriaList As String = "Yellow,Red"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Last Row
    Dim cel As Range
    Set cel = ws.Cells.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
    If cel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = cel.Row
    If LastRow < FirstRow Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Copy-Columns Range
    Dim ccrg As Range: Set ccrg = ws.Columns(CopyColsAddress)
    
    ' Criteria
    Dim CritCols() As String: CritCols = Split(CritColsList, ",")
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(CritCols)
    
    ' Additional Variables
    Dim trg As Range ' Total Range
    Dim i As Long ' Range Row Counter
    Dim n As Long ' Criteria Counter
    
    ' Loop and combine matched row ranges in Total Range.
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        For n = 0 To cUpper
            If ws.Cells(i, CritCols(n)).Value = Criteria(n) Then
                If trg Is Nothing Then
                    Set trg = ccrg.Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set trg = Union(trg, ccrg.Rows(i))
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next n
    Next i
    
    ' Select (Copy, Delete)
    If Not trg Is Nothing Then
        ' Often we do something like:
        'trg.Copy Sheet2.Range("A2")
        ws.Activate
        trg.Select
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that when OP says _"based on the value of whatever cell"._ it implied to search in all cells.

Comment: @EEM: I based my answer on the first three sentences discarding the rest since it didn't mention red or yellow anymore. My bad. I never noticed the `Find` parameters being wrong. Nicely spotted.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, trying to show another approach demonstrating the dynamic possibilities of version 2019+ plus a tricky use of the `Union()` range function:

```
Sub ExampleCall()
    '[0] define search item
    Const SearchItem As String = "My text"
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Sheet1.UsedRange                   ' Project's sheet Code(Name)
    '[1] evaluate condition
    Dim condition$: condition = "=IF(" & rng.Address & "=""" & SearchItem & """,ROW(" & rng.Address & "),"""")"
    Dim chk: chk = Evaluate(condition)
    '[2] get findings
    Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = Range("E" & rng.Rows.Count + 1)  ' set dummy range (avoiding later checks for Is Nothing)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(chk)
        If Not IsError(Application.Average(Application.Index(chk, i, 0))) Then
            Set rng1 = Union(rng1, Intersect(Rows(i), Range("E:BH")))
            '' ... or do something with data field row Application.Index(chk, i, 0)
            '  ...
        End If
    Next i
    '[3] select rows with findings (after removing dummy from union range)
    If rng1.Areas.Count > 1 Then rng1.Areas(1).Delete ' delete dummy
    rng1.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: A big thank you for the invite. Shocking ('lack of knowledge'), as usual. I'll definitely try to adopt the 'dummy idea'. I don't understand the `Evaluate` since I rarely use it and of course, the `Average/Index` combination: **yet!** I definitely want to figure it out on my own. I'll get back to you in a day or two. Btw, I prefer `Columns("E:BH").Rows(i)` (no need for `Intersect` (no big deal)).

Comment: _A word of caution:_ `Application.Evaluate` applies the formula to the `ActiveSheet`, as such suggest to either `.Activate` the `Sheet` or include the `Sheet.Name` as part of the range (i.e. `"Table!" & rng.Address`). You can test this by running the procedure with another `Sheet` active and insert a `Stop` after `Dim chk: chk = Evaluate(condition)`

Comment: @EEM - appreciate the valuable hints; especially because usually I'm plaiding for fully qualified range references.

Answer (score 2):

This proposed solution uses `Filter` to identify the target rows, extracts them to a `Dictionary` and post the dictionary to a Sheet named `Output`.

```
Sub Get_Rows()
Const kFml As String = "= ""|"" & #WSH!#RNG & ""|""" 'Wrap the values between "|" to ensure exact matches only
Dim Dtn As Object
Dim aTarget As Variant, aData As Variant, aDataX As Variant
Dim aRowTrg As Variant, aRowFnd As Variant
Dim vValue As Variant, sFml As String, lRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Table")
        
        Rem Get Target Values Array (Two methods pick one)
        Rem 1. 'Provided (hard-coded)
        'aTarget = [{"Red","Yellow"}]
        Rem 2. Obtained from a range - adjust as required
        sFml = Replace(Replace(kFml, "#WSH", .Name), "#RNG", "B2:B3")
        aTarget = Application.Transpose(Application.Evaluate(sFml))
        
        Rem Get Data Range to Array
        With Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("E:BH"))
            aData = .Value
            sFml = Replace(Replace(kFml, "#WSH", .Worksheet.Name), "#RNG", .Address)
            aDataX = Application.Evaluate(sFml)
    
    End With: End With
    
    Set Dtn = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Dtn
    
        Rem Add Header to Dictionary
        .Add 1 + .Count, Application.Index(aData, 1, 0)
    
        Rem Search & Add Rows to Dictionary
        For lRow = 2 To UBound(aData)
            
            Rem Set Target Row
            aRowTrg = Application.Index(aDataX, lRow, 0)
            For Each vValue In aTarget
                
                Rem Filter Row with Value
                aRowFnd = Filter(aRowTrg, vValue, True)
                If UBound(aRowFnd) > -1 Then
                    
                    Rem Add Target Row to Dictionary
                    .Add 1 + .Count, Application.Index(aData, lRow, 0)
                    Exit For
                
        End If: Next: Next
        
        Rem Post Dictionary to Sheet [Output] Range [E:BH]
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("E:BH").Rows(1).Resize(.Count).Value = _
            Application.Index(Dtn.items, 0, 0)
    
    End With

End Sub
```

**Table**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

Comment: Rem Helpful, solid and enriching above solutions by a Filter/Dictionary approach +:)